# React native TextInput has a different height compared to a Text in android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

As you can see in the image below, I have created a `TextInput` on the bottom (red one) and a `Text` above that (green one). They have the same font, font size, and font weight and nothing more. But the `TextInput` (in my case) is 28dp when I inspect it with devtools and the `Text` is 23dp, it's also obvious from the picture that the `TextInput` height is bigger. I have tried setting `padding`, `paddingBottom`, `paddingTop` and `paddingVertical` to 0, but it didn't help. I have even tried adding underline to the `Text`, but It didn't change its height.

Likewise, I have also tested this on latest react-native CLI and expo.

There is also this [expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@ahmafi/textinput-height-bug) if you want to try it out yourself.

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: seems it appears this way only in expo when you open in browser. I tried it on real device and everything seems normal

Comment: @paperskyline For me, it's the same on physical device too! What is your android version?

Comment: I tested it on android 12

Comment: Weird! I have the same version on my physicall device!